# What is the hotkey to show Chrome extensions?

Tags: google-chrome, hotkeys

What is the hotkey to show Chrome extensions?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is none built-in; you'll have to install an extension specifically for this such as "[Extensions HotKey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bipafflnnjbnnbicjcefmakbgaaofgle)" or use a shortcut/hotkey management extension (like "[BookmarkBar HotKeys](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/epljiamjefebpckdcbjelbbmepgancpg)") and assign the extension page (`chrome://extensions/`) to a key combo.

Comment: you can now get keyboard shortcut access to Chrome's extensions (without installing additional extensions) by adding a hack entry to Google's stored search engines. See my answer below for more detail.

Answer (score 23):

- Right-click in the Chrome address bar
- Select "Edit search engines..." from the menu
- Scroll down to "Site search"
- Click the "Add" button at the right
- Where you see:

  - "Add a new search engine" enter any name (e.g. "Chrome Extensions")
  - "Keyword" enter your desired shortcut (e.g., <kbd>E</kbd> )
  - "URL..." enter "chrome://extensions/"
- Select "Done"
- Now you can get to the Chrome Extensions page from within Chrome via <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: And welcome to SuperUser!

Comment: Excellent answer!

Comment: This is the best answer. Simple, doesn't require any extra extensions.

Comment: The URL should be "chrome://extensions/"

Comment: @JanacMeena Thank you. I fixed it.

Comment: I was looking for another use case, just opening an extension via text inputs.
I added a "site search" and then set Name, keyword and URL in there.
Now I can CTRL N for new tab, type "keyword" tab and anykey, then enter and it opens that URL which is the popup.html page of the extension

Answer (score 9):

On Mac OS X, there is none by default, if you mean *Window » Extensions*. Just add one in *System Preferences*:

[image]

Result:

[image]

---

Or you can always enter (and even bookmark) `chrome://extensions/` to get there.

Comment: What if there are multiple menu items with the same name?

Answer (score 5):

I use this sequence: Alt+F > L > E

Answer (score 3):

You can write a very simple extension to do that.

define the shortcut in the extension's manifest : https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands

```
"commands": {
        "open-extensions-tab": {
            "suggested_key": {
                "default": "Ctrl+Shift+E",
                "windows": "Ctrl+Shift+E",
                "mac": "Command+Shift+E",
                "linux": "Ctrl+Shift+E"
            },
            "description": "Open Extensions Tab"
        }
    }
```

And a one line background script to listen to shortcuts defined in the extension's manifest like this :

```
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(function(command){if(command=="open-extensions-tab")chrome.tabs.create({url:"chrome://extensions/"});});
```

This will add a Ctrl+Shift+E shortcut to open the extensions tab

I made a repo for this, read the code, download it, and load it as an unpacked extension from the extensions tab

update : extension will check other chrome windows and focus window + tab if necessary.

https://github.com/nicopowa/ChromeExtensionShortcut

Answer (score 1):

What you could do (what i do) is that I use the shortcut Ctrl+  H (History) and then select Extensions.

Answer (score 1):

I created a small [Autohotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) script to get there quickly:

```
; Bound to "F1"
F1::
IfWinActive, New Tab
    ; Focus address bar
    Send ^l
else
    ; Open new tab
    Send ^t

SendInput chrome`:`/`/extensions`/{Enter}
```

Answer (score 0):

A long one but works well.

At first, didn't feel good one, but it is good enough.

1. Ctrl + H
2. Alt + D, right arrow > shift control left arrow > delete > press E
   OR type extensions (only once)
3. press ENTER

Answer (score 0):

MacOS: I've found a simpler way. Create a bookmark for the extensions shortcut page and create a custom shortcut for it in System Preferences.

**STEP 1**

- Create a bookmark for Chrome Extension Shortcuts. Navigate to
  chrome://extensions/shortcuts.
- Bookmark this page and give it a name that you'll remember. Once it's
  bookmarked, you'll notice that it appears under the Bookmarks menu,
  under its own line (with the Name you've given it).

[Bookmark the Chrome Extensions Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Umlg5.png)

**STEP 2**

- Open System Preferences and then Keyboard and click on the shortcuts
  tab. Hit App Shortcuts and then the "+" button. This will add a
  custom shortcut for any app. In the dialog, you will see a list for
  "Application". Select Chrome from the dropdown.
- Below, you'll see "Menu Title", here enter the name you've given your
  bookmark above. Lastly, assign a short-cut. Viola, done. Now you can
  use that short cut and it will pull up the extensions shortcut page.

[Select Chrome, and in "Menu Title", enter the name of the bookmark in step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQaX3.jpg)